# How to view NFT token on Goerli network with GUI?

Tags: nft, goerli

I deployed an NFT-smart-contract ("0xeC490239A5FD733005a84c88C988f04E2A5D4AE1") on Goerli Network and minted an ERC721 token by the command below (tx hash x06ad1421d0a4cac645940f8f1f3f513cc90b30cd51a41832590fed45e894b802).

With Etherscan, I can see my image url in the input data field as a string but not as an image.
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x06ad1421d0a4cac645940f8f1f3f513cc90b30cd51a41832590fed45e894b802
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmafQXEmkT6bfRDvDvoicb9aJrhMQ84rxYE4UFtryddPQF

But Etherscan does not automatically show the images to visitors. Do you know any nice website which shows images by default for Ethereum Goerli network? Thank you.

(https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x06ad1421d0a4cac645940f8f1f3f513cc90b30cd51a41832590fed45e894b802)

```
abi = [...]
contract=eth.contract(abi).at("0xeC490239A5FD733005a84c88C988f04E2A5D4AE1")
contract.mintNFT.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[0],"https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmafQXEmkT6bfRDvDvoicb9aJrhMQ84rxYE4UFtryddPQF",{from:eth.accounts[0]})
```

Answer (score 1):

looksrare has a marketplace for goerli, you can try this link: https://goerli.looksrare.org/